# Abnormal permission request behaviour on Android 13 Tiramisù

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-13, android-tiramisu

I have a method in order to show request permissions if needed

```
   static boolean requestPermission(int id, String... permissions) {
            System.out.println("REQUEST PERMISSION METHOD");
            boolean granted = true;
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            
            for (String s : permissions) {
                int check = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, s);
                boolean hasPermission = (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                granted &= hasPermission;
                if (!hasPermission) {
                    list.add(s);
                }
            }

            if (granted) {
                return true;
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[permissionsNeeded.size()]), id);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This method worked till Android 13 that I'm testing with latest official Android emulator in Android Studio, now if `onResume()` I call e.g.

```
    requestPermission(id,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
```

I have a loop of inconclusive requests: I don't get any crash but in log cat I have continue `"REQUEST PERMISSION METHOD"` prints, the string print placed at the start of the method as if the method is invoked continuously somehow.

Why this? How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact the `Manifest.permission.*` constants you are try to get are no longer valid if you target newer Android versions.
This cause problems with your

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)
```

So, enwrap the requests with proper API level check or target a lower android version till you have the app properly migrated to SAF (so you don't need direct storage access and related permissions).